# Multiple value in CheckListBox

Tags: delphi, checkbox, multiple-value

How to implement this case:
I have CheckListBox with 20 items: Symptomp 1, Symptomp 2,.., Symptomp 20. User can select more than one symptomp. Something that make me confuse is, how to give multiple value for each of symptomp. Here is my code:

```
  for i := 0 to CheckListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if CheckListBox1.Checked[i] = True then
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Append(CheckListBox1.Items.Strings[i]);
      if i = 0 
        p1 := 'Disease 1';
        p2 := 'Disease 2';
        p3 := 'Disease 3';
      if i = 1 then
        p1 := 'Disease 2';
      if i = 2 then
        p1 := 'Disease 1';
      if i = 3 then
        p1 := 'Disease 3';
      if i = 4 then
        p1 := 'Disease 2';
        p2 := 'Disease 3';
      if i = 5 then
        p1 := 'Disease 1';
        p2 := 'Disease 5';
        p3 := 'Disease 6';
      if i = 6 then
        p1 := 'Disease 5';

      Memo1.Lines.Add('Disease:' + p1+', '+p2+', '+p3);
      Memo1.Lines.Add('');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

But the result is not as i expected. How to make p1,p2,p3 dinamically ?

Here is the result when i check at index 2,4,6:

```
Symptomp 3
Disease:Disease 1, Disease 5, Disease 6

Symptomp 5
Disease:Disease 2, Disease 5, Disease 6

Symptomp 7
Disease:Disease 5, Disease 5, Disease 6
```

Comment: The output is what the code defines. What do you want to happen?

Comment: I want to make an array to save p1,p2,p3 value for each of Disease.

Comment: It's not very clear, could you make few examples of what you want to get and what you actually get?

Comment: @Marco for further process, I need to get wich Disease is selected based on Checked Symptomp. I am confuse how to explain my problem. -_-

Comment: It's not remotely clear to me what you want

Comment: Do you want a set of diseases matching all selected symptoms?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Me too.. :( I dont know how to explain

Comment: @LURD Yeah.. That is.. :D

Comment: I think you've started coding too soon. You need a clear understanding of your goals before coding. When you start coding you also need to separate gui from logic better.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for your suggestion. ;)
#KeepStudying and #Fighting.. #Yosh

Comment: @Alca, is my answer what you wanted to achieve? The total list of diseases are collected in a set. The business logic is separated from the GUI, which is what you should learn how to abstract.

Comment: @LURD : Yuph. Thanks for your help. ;)

Comment: @Alca, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a list of diseases and a constant string array to match:

```
// List of diseases
type
  // Note: Use descriptive names instead of a numbers
  TDisease = (td1,td2,td3,{..,}tdMaxDiseases);
  TDiseaseSet = set of TDisease;

  TSymptom = (ts1,ts2,ts3,{..,}tsMaxSymptoms);

const
  // A list of disease names
  sDisease: array[TDisease] of String =
    ('Disease 1','Disease 2','Disease 3',{..,}'Disease xx');
  // An array of disease sets corresponding to each symptom
  cMyDiseaseSet : array[TSymptom] of TDiseaseSet = ([td1,td2,td3],[td3],[td1],[td2]);
```

The set constant array declares a set of diseases for each symptom.

---

To get a resulting string for each symptom and a set with diseases matching the symptom:

```
// A Function to retrieve the diseases from a symptom
function DiseaseFromSymptom(aSymptom: TSymptom; var diseaseSet: TDiseaseSet): String;
var
  aDisease: TDisease;
begin
  diseaseSet := cMyDiseaseSet[aSymptom];
  Result := '';
  for aDisease in diseaseSet do
    Result := Result + sDisease[aDisease] + ', ';
  SetLength(Result,Length(Result)-2);
end;
```

---

```
var
  diseases,diseasesSummary: TDiseaseSet;
  s: String;

  diseasesSummary := [];
  for i := 0 to CheckListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if CheckListBox1.Checked[i] = True then
    begin
      s := DiseaseFromSymptom(TSymptom(i),diseases);
      Memo1.Lines.Append(CheckListBox1.Items.Strings[i]);
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Disease:' + s);
      Memo1.Lines.Add('');
      // Insert diseases
      diseasesSummary := diseasesSummary + diseases;
    end;
  end;
  // A complete set of diseases in diseasesSummary
```

---

It seems as you want a set of diseases matching all checked symptoms. The latest update shows how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason you don't get expected result is that you never clear the `p1`, `p2` and `p3` variables, so if `CheckListBox1.Checked[0]` is true then `p2` and `p3` will be assigned, then if `CheckListBox1.Checked[1]` is true too then `p2` and `p3`will still have a value from previous iteration while they probably should be blank. Try something like

```
for i := 0 to CheckListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if CheckListBox1.Checked[i] = True then
    begin
      p1 := '';
      p2 := '';
      p3 := '';

      Memo1.Lines.Append(CheckListBox1.Items.Strings[i]);

      if i = 0 then begin
        p1 := 'Disease 1';
        p2 := 'Disease 2';
        p3 := 'Disease 3';
      end;
      ...    
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Disease:' + p1+', '+p2+', '+p3);
      Memo1.Lines.Add('');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It doesnt give an effect.